# If a sequence of $100$ real numbers is such that the average of any $7$ terms is equal to the average of some $11$ terms, then all terms are equal

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> We have a sequence of real numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{100}$ such that the average of every 7 terms is equal to average of some 11 terms. Show that $a_1=\cdots a_{100}$

Have tried this with pigeon hole and divisibility , only thing I got was that all the number's would have same remainder when divided by 7(r1) and 11(r2).If i do the same thing again and again using $a_1 =7k_1+r , a_2=7k_2+r, \ldots$
I again get $k_1$ to be divisible by 7 but how do I use this . How do I prove that they are equal

Comment: Start by considering the average of the *smallest* 7 numbers. P.S. Since it's a sequence of *real* numbers (not necessarily integers) `divisibility` doesn't apply.

Comment: Hint: Wolog $a_1 \le a_2 \etc... $.  You can prove average of smallest 7 is average of smallest 11 so average of a_8 to a_1 is the same average.

Comment: yeah but that proves first 11 number's to be same we cannot say that for all 100 numbers but yeah i did not think this before let me think a bit more on the same lines

Comment: I cannot proceed with this . I know smallest 11 terms are equal and largest 11 terms are equal . But i cannot think about anything after that

Comment: "average of every 7 terms" means "of every consecutive 7 terms" or "of every 7 terms whatever" ?

Comment: Average of every 7 whatever terms . At-least that is what I have been trying but from where I found it (http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1183491p5739027), asker did not mention source so cannot guarantee that statement is perfectly correct .

Comment: If all are different, we will have $\binom{100}{7}$ distinct values needing to match $\binom{100}{11}$ distinct values which doesn't work. Even if we have $97$ equal and $3$ different, we will get $8$ equations and $4$ unknowns. So at most $1$ or $2$ can be different and we can easily solve these cases and show they are all equal.

Answer (score 0):

A start, but I didn't reach the contradiction I expected.  There must be an easy way to show you keep adding points indefinitely if two of the $a$'s have different values.

You say in the comments that you can show the smallest eleven are the same and the largest eleven are the same.  If we have a group of $a$'s that work, we ca add or subtract a constant from all of them and multiply by another constant so the smallest number is $0$ and the next smallest number is $1$.  Consider six of the smallest and the $1$.  Their average is $\frac 17$  If your group of $11$ has two terms not equal to $0$ that are at least $1$ the average will be too high, if it has only one it must be $\frac {11}7$, which must be in the set.  Now we can take $\frac {11}7$ with six of the zeros and get an average of $\frac {11}{49}$.  The sum of the eleven that match this average is $\frac {121}{49}.$  If we have two numbers in the group of eleven with this average greater than $0$, neither can be $\frac {11}7$ as the other would be less than $1$.

Comment: sorry but if it has one very big number it could be the same